# Assigning popups in bulk for markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am making a map of my campus (non-geographical) that contains many markers, let's say one for each classroom.

What i want to do is make it so that each marker has its own popup that displays the classroom code eg: `'E003'` (ideally with a mouse hover, but onclick is serviceable). Given that there will be ***many*** with the exact same pattern, and that the format of the popup will be subject to change in the future, i want a way to assign them all at once and not write 6+ lines for every single marker that i create.

Just to clarify, i only need 1 popup per marker.

I created markers and added them to the list like so:

```js
var salaE001 = L.marker([2869, 653], title = "Sala E001", riseOnHover = true, interactive = true).addTo(map);
markers.push(salaE001)
```

I already tried this, which i found as a part of the answer to a different question in StackExchange:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var currentMarker = markers[i];
    currentMarker.bindPopup(this.title);
}
```

But what happens is that every marker gets the popup of the last one in the list, making them all the same.

e.g. every classroom gets the same `'E003'` popup.

I figured that using `this.title` instead of, say, `currentMarker.title` was iffy, but the latter didn't even do anything at all.

Every other solution that i tried doesn't even assign the markers at all, and breaks the map.

Comment: From your code sample, you indeed assign the _same_ `this.title` to _all_ your Markers... could you describe how you originally populate the `this.title` property? Ideally provide a [mcve].

Comment: I added and example, and as i clarified in the edit, it seemed odd to me still, but thats how i found the snippet originally.

Comment: While `L.marker(coords, title = "Sala E001")` is not illegal in JS, it does not do what you probably expect. I can only guess that `this.title` is set somewhere else in your code, but without a [mcve] it is difficult to say how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your marker creation is wrong. Instead of passing a object of properties you are assigning values to variables.

```
L.marker([2869, 653], title = "Sala E001", riseOnHover = true, interactive = true).addTo(map);
```

should be:

```
L.marker([2869, 653], {title: "Sala E001", riseOnHover: true, interactive: true}).addTo(map);
```

So your script should look like:

```
var markers = [];
var salaE001 = L.marker([0, 0], {title: "Sala E001", riseOnHover: true, interactive: true}).addTo(map);
markers.push(salaE001);

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var currentMarker = markers[i];
    currentMarker.bindPopup(currentMarker.options.title);
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/M5n63wmdn40YTVwJ